# Nautilus hangs searching for network locations

Tags: networking, nautilus, 16.10

After an upgrade to 16.10 on one machine and a clean install of 16.10 on another I have an intermittent problem with nautilus when I try to open other locations.  Under the Networks part of the window I get the message "Searching for network locations" and the spinner spinning, but nothing happens.  The other locations are on line, checked by pinging them, and everything is on the same wired network (tho' the same behaviour occurs when I take the laptop and use a wireless connection). Sometimes logging out and back in solves the problem, sometimes a reboot, and sometimes nothing works until a few hours later when I can connect with no problem.  I'm using the same smb.conf file that worked under several previous versions of Ubuntu.

Is it nautilus or some other subtle interaction introduced with 16.10?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too and I know how stressful this can be.

Searching through google and trying some changes I found one solution.

The steps are:

1 - We Need to do changes in smb.conf (/etc/samba/smb.conf). You can do this with gedit, nano or some else program. With gedit is like this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

2 - Then we need to find the constant/variable "name resolve order". In my case this constant has the value equals to wins lmhosts bcast host. I don't know if this changes something, but I change "wins lmhosts bcast host" to "wins bcast lmhosts host". So, my final is "name resolve order = wins lmhosts bcast host".

3 - I added this lines in smb.conf at the final.

```
netbios name = <hostname>
client lanman auth = yes
client ntlmv2 auth = no
```

You can find your hostname, typing "hostname" in your terminal, then just change  by your terminal answer.

Now i don't have more this issues:
1 - networking timeout
2 - nautilus searching for network and not able to find.
3 - disconnecting from mounted network folder when not using.
4 - nautilus crashing after disconnect and trying to connect to mounted folder.
5 - Nautilus can't connect after "nmbd restart" and "smbd restart" (Sometimes this commands works and others not, to recover the network).

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried part 2, but even after adding the lines in part 3 I still have the same problem.  It's an irritant, but I can usually get a connection after a couple of reboots.  The NAS I have on the network is always accessible using a web interface even when I can't connect through Nautilus.

Comment: hi Richard, just to keep in mind. Do you change <hostname> to your terminal answer right?

Comment: Yes, they match.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening more and more.  As a work around I have found that starting a Nautilus session from the command line like this

```
nautilus --new-window smb://<local ip address>
```

works.